# C++ - DLL injection and call function

Tags: c++, dll

Long time i'm trying to find a answer for my question.

I have a game DLL and a program.

I the DLL I have a function that changes something in the game. (if the DLL is injected into the game). The program is my injector.

My question is, after injection, how is it possible to manually call a function in the DLL?

Now this function is called when is attached to the game, but how to call this function from the injector?

Comment: Surely you don't need all those capital letters.

Comment: I did something like that a long long time ago but I can't remember the details. Can't you create a new thread in the other process and have that thread call the function? **+** Take a look at this:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682437%28VS.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can create a remote thread on a running process and on that thread you make your way to that function that you mention.

Comment: "make your way to" -- no, not really.  You'd better be specifying the function you want to run as the thread entrypoint, because there's no existing code in the target that will call the function for you.

Comment: Can u give me example ? To run function in DLL with 2 args (int, char *) in injected program from injector ?

Comment: @user2652995: You can't.  You can only remotely call a function that is a valid thread procedure.  However, that thread procedure can call other functions within its injected DLL.

Comment: @BenVoigt This is exactly what I am trying to say in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

In order to call the function, you need code that executes in the target process. That's the game, but you want to invoke the function from your injector, a different process. You already have code in the target process, the DLL that you injected. So, get the injected DLL to call the function. Some ways to achieve that:

1. Create another remote thread in the target process that calls a function defined in the DLL. That can then do whatever it likes, in the context of the target process.
2. Use some IPC mechanism (e.g. named pipes, sockets, etc.) to ask the injected DLL to carry out the action.

Comment: Please give me example code, bcoz in theory i don't understand nothing ;P

Comment: No can do, sorry. It's your job to write the code, not mine. You already wrote code to inject the DLL, so you must know how to do that.  Or did you cut and paste it all?

Answer (score -1):

You have to load the symbol (function) from the dll into your program.

That symbol would be a function pointer that you can call.  There are significant differences between operating systems so I would search for "call function from dll" to get an example for your OS.

Comment: The function pointer isn't valid in the injector's address space, and calling a function pointer would run inside the injector, not in the target.